# Google App Script Authorization error for Java

Tags: java, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I was able to send a string from App Script to Java Application using
a single function. For instance:

```
function returnText() {
  return "Hello"; 
}
```

Java application is able to print the string to a command line.

However, when I add multiple functions to Google App Script, I get an
authorization error. Please see the error below:

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401
Unauthorized

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The function that I added calls GoogleDoc using *DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()* function. To access GoogleDoc, we need to define the scope *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents* in the Java code that runs locally.

Comment: I don't get it. There is no content in the link, but a simple word "documents."

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you needed. A documentation about [Handling errors: revoked or invalid tokens](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/practices#handling_errors_revoked_or_invalid_tokens).

> Google Drive apps should account for the API returning an `HTTP 401`
>   or `HTTP 403` response when calling the Drive API. These errors could
>   indicate any of:
>
> - Token expiry.
> - Token revocation. This would cause both the access token and the refresh token to stop working.
> - Token not authorized for needed scopes.
> - Request not authorized correctly with OAuth 2.0 protocol.
>
> Token expiry can be handled by refreshing the credentials. If that
>   call fails with an "Invalid Credentials" error, the issue is probably
>   that the user has revoked access. For revoked access and all issues
>   other than token expiry, the best remedy is to redirect the user
>   through the OAuth dialog to re-grant access.

Comment: Thank You for the help. I believe this is related to scope issue since adding new function means adding more scope into Google App Script; therefore, Java Application has to have a right to access these scopes to call the App Script. Otherwise, we got an error. However, I do not know how to solve this and the link you gave does not mention about the solution.

Comment: So... We need to get an OAuth token and send it in the Http Request... Am I right?